# Finding consecutive odd number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The negative of the sum of 2 consecutive odd numbers is less than -45 , which of the following may be one of the numbers?

$A)21 $

$B) 23 $

$C) 26 $

$D) 22 $

$ C) 24$

What will be logic to solve this problem.

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked about 15 questions during one week. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, stackexchange software will not allow you to do so.) For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you ! I have already had in my mind ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the consecutive odd numbers be $2n-1, 2n+1$ where $n$ is any integer

So, $-(2n-1+2n+1)<-45\iff 4n>45\implies n\ge 12$

For $n=12, 2n-1=23;2n+1=25$

For $n=13, 2n-1=25;2n+1=27$ and so on

Comment: can you elaborate how you took $12$

Comment: @SSK, $4n>45, n>\frac{45}4=11+\frac14$  As $n$ is an integer, $n\ge 12$

Answer (score 1):

Let consecutive odd numbers be $x,x+2$

then, $-(x+(x+2))<-45\implies -(2x+2)<-45$

Multiplying both sides by $-1$; since multiplying by a negative quantity inverts the inequality, therefore

$2x+2>45\implies 2x>43\implies x>21.5$

Therefore, smaller odd number must be greater than $21.5\implies$ both odd numbers must be greater than $21.5$

Only odd number in the options are $21$ and $23$, so $23$ is the correct answer.